# Encrypt URL parameter return NULL issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption, qr-code

I'm trying to encrypt URL parameter ID in ASP.NET. I have built a simple project with `IDataProtector`.
But I am getting a `Null` reference error in the line pointed in the sample code.

**Controller:**

```
 private readonly IDataProtector protector;

    public QRScanningController(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, DataPro dataPro)
    {          
            protector = dataProtectionProvider.Create(dataPro.EmpIdRoutValue);            
    }

    public QRScanningController()
    {
        //protector = dataProtectionProvider.Create(dataPro.EmpIdRoutValue);
    }
    
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        
        DataPro dataProobj = new DataPro();
        dataProobj.id = 12131;
        dataProobj.encID = protector.Protect(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataProobj.id.ToString())); **//the issue in this line return Null value.**
        return View(dataProobj);
    }

    public ActionResult QRscan(string encID)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You did not mention what the error is. Also `DataPro dataProobj = new DataPro(); ` where is the ID getting set?

Comment: Dear Rahatur thanks for reply, the issue mentioned as comment in code, please review the code, the issue returned null , DataPro is model class

Comment: I can see that the ID property was not assigned after creating the object. Can you confirm if the `dataProobj.id.ToString()` is not null?

Comment: I debug dataProobj.id.ToString() and returned 12131, the issue in line dataProobj.encID, the program stopped here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Protect` function also takes a string as a parameter. So no need to convert the Id to a byte.
Change your code in the `Index` to be as followings:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;

...
dataProobj.encID = protector.Protect(dataProobj.id.ToString());
...
```

That worked for me.

[image]

Comment: thanks Rahatur for your efforts, dataProobj.id.ToString() shows error "cannot convert from string to byte[]"

Comment: I searched for this issue a lot but I did not find any answer , is there any package I should install or call, or something missing?

Comment: @AsmaAlghamdi Add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` package from Nuget manager